array with rotated text in one column (not in header)
I need to make an array/table where I put vertical text in one of the columns (not in the header), like this:
What is the most natural/painless way to make such an array, short of using tikz hack?  THANKS!
Note: I colored the vertical text in red to highlight what I want; in the actual table all text will be black.

Please -- as usual here -- show the code you have so far. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

I'm not convinced you need to rotate the row headers in the left column, but it's hard to say without knowing what * is supposed to mean.

The nicematrix package has the \rotate command.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
\NiceMatrixOptions{
    custom-line ={command = hwideline, tikz={}, width=1ex}}
\begin{NiceArray}{c|c|c|c|c}
\Block{1-2}{} && \text{case 1} & \text{case 2} & \text{case 3}\\\hwideline
\Block{3-1}{\rotate A>B} & x>0 & ** & ** & **\\
 & x<0 & ** & ** & **\\
 & x=0 & ** & ** & **\\[1ex]\hwideline
\Block{2-1}{\rotate A<B} & x\ge0 & ** & ** & **\\
 & x<0 & ** & ** & **\\[1ex]\hwideline
\Block{3-1}{\rotate A=B} & x>0 & ** & ** & **\\
 & x<0 & ** & ** & **\\
 & x=0 & ** & ** & **
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}


Another possibility is to use tabularray, makecelandrotating` package:
Edit
The first column is for unknown reason to wide. This can be resolved (at least temporally until the cause will not be find) with defining lefts and rights for the first column specifications:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{rotating, 
            makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{hline{2,5,7}, 
             vline{3-Y},    vline{2}={2-Z}{},
              colspec = {Q[mode=math, leftsep=-12pt, rightsep=0pt, % <---
                           cmd = \settowidth\rotheadsize{ABC}\rotcell] 
                          Q[c, mode=math]  ccc},
              cell{2,7}{1} = {r=3}{c},  % <----
              cell{5}{1}   = {r=2}{c},  % <----
              row{1} = {rowsep = -2pt},
              }
    &       &   case 1  
                    &   case 2  
                            &   case 3      \\
A>B & x>0   & **    & **    & **  \\
    & x<0   & **    & **    & **  \\
    & x=0   & **    & **    & **  \\
A<B & x\ge0 & **    & **    & **  \\
    & x<0   & **    & **    & **  \\
A=B & x>0   & **    & **    & **  \\
    & x<0   & **    & **    & **  \\
    & x=0   & **    & **    & **
\end{tblr}
\end{document}



It would be nicer to remove the leftmost lines.

@projetmbc, it is not entirely clear (to me, at least) what  table should present. Provided code only reproduce in question showed image.

Something like hline{2,5,7}={2-Z}{}, vline{3-Y},.

@projetmbc, that is matter of taste. Step forward can be for table lines use hline{2,5,7}={2-Z}{}, vline{2-Z}={2-Z}{},. Since so far there is no OP response on answers, we don't know what (s)he like to have. Until then I will not change my answer
